# How to increase Youtube API quota

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have developed a news website. Partners are allowed to submit articles (video articles) via a dedicated form.
We want the videos to be hosted on Youtube then embedded on the website.
We have a working prototype.
The problem is the Youtube API Quota. Youtube offers 10k units per day. An upload costs 1600, which basically means after 6 videos, we can't use the API.

We've tried to click on the button to increase the quota from the console, but the max value is 10k (which makes no sense btw).
We've filled the dedicated form multiple time, we've contacted our former Youtube sales guy who said couldn't help. We even managed to have a Google representative on the phone who said he didn't know how it works and that we should discuss that with Youtube directly.

Does anyone know how to proceed? We're willing to pay the extra units, but even for that, we can't find the proper procedure.
Most of websites and threads dealing with the issue are old one when quotas were very high.

Comment: I've received a compliance review kindly asking to fill in the same form again...

Comment: No one from Youtube that can help ? Come on guys, your procedure to increase the quota is a mess and no one seems to have a solid answer. I've filled in your form half a dozen times...